# importing pkg.sub as other.sub

Tags: python, python-import

I don't have this problem, but it came to my mind while I was working on a related issue. Let's have:

```
logging = 'something'  # bad naming decision
import logging as lg   # using a different name
```

How do you import `logging.config` as `lg.config` without overwriting the original `logging`?

After some testing I found this:

```
import logging.config as _  # any unused name
```

But is it really correct? Are there better solutions?

Comment: assign the value of `logging` to a temporary variable, and reassign it after the import?

Comment: In this particular case you should be able to reference ``lg.config`` without an ``import logging.config`` statement since you have already defined an alias of ``lg`` for ``logging``. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @PaWa `import logging` does not pull the `config` module (on my Python version at least). OTOH `import os` imports also `os.path`. I think it depends on the implementation and each sub-module should be imported explicitly.

Comment: @MaartenFabré yes, that would make a well readable code

Comment: @VPfB Off course that's not the most readable solution, but it limits the uglyness to 1 place where you can easily document it, and it makes the intent more clear than `import logging.config as _`. The best solution would be to refactor the code to rename the variable

Comment: @MaartenFabré I'm not sure why you wrote "Off course that's not the most readable solution". I still think the readability is the advantage of your solution to this hypothetical problem.

Comment: i meant elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing something like this ?

```
import logging as lg
from logging import config
```

After this both `config` and `lg.config` refer to `logging.config`.

```
In [3]: config
Out[3]: <module 'logging.config' from 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\logging\\config.py'>

In [4]: lg.config
Out[4]: <module 'logging.config' from 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\logging\\config.py'>
```

Answer (score -1):

After setting the alias you still have to import it with the full path, but you can still call the sub modules with the alias:

```
import my_module as mm
import my_module.sub_module

mm.sub_module
```

Comment: The second import overwrites 'my_module'. The question was how to avoid it.